# Configuring Gunicorn with nginx - nginx displaying 500 Internal Server Error when running on port 8000

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn, production

I'm having issues while setting up nginx and Gunicorn on my local computer (not the server). I have a Django project and I want to be able to access it via http://localhost:8000/. Before my nginx was functional, my Gunicorn server was able to start successfully. However, once I got my nginx server configured, now my Gunicorn server won't start because nginx is already running on my localhost on port 8000. When I visit http://localhost:8000/ I get `500 - Internal Server Error`. When I visit http://localhost:80/, however, I get `Welcome to nginx!` web page.

To configure nginx and Gunicorn, I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-10), skipping steps 5 to 7 (inclusive). I have to note that in my `/etc/nginx` the `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories didn't exist, so I had to make them.

I have only two files in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory - `default` and `mydjangoproject`. Both have the same contents and both have their symbolic links in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. Their contents are:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /production_static/ {
        root /home/john/Documents/Django_projects/mydjangoproject/Version_2/mydjangoproject;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant parts of my Django project's `settings.py` file:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'production_static/')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Here is the error log from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2020/12/20 11:58:09 [emerg] 23584#23584: open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydjangoproject:11
2020/12/20 12:01:59 [emerg] 23773#23773: open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydjangoproject:11
2020/12/20 12:02:04 [emerg] 23775#23775: open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydjangoproject:11
2020/12/20 12:02:05 [emerg] 23777#23777: open() "/etc/nginx/proxy_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydjangoproject:11
2020/12/20 12:12:25 [error] 22879#22879: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2020/12/20 13:51:08 [error] 22879#22879: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2020/12/20 13:55:01 [error] 25938#25938: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:55:01 [error] 25938#25938: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:55:04 [error] 25938#25938: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:55:21 [error] 25938#25938: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:55:21 [error] 25938#25938: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:55:22 [error] 25938#25938: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:55:23 [error] 25938#25938: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:56:00 [error] 25938#25938: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:56:48 [warn] 25999#25999: conflicting server name "127.0.0.1" on 0.0.0.0:8000, ignored
2020/12/20 13:57:11 [warn] 26011#26011: conflicting server name "127.0.0.1" on 0.0.0.0:8000, ignored
2020/12/20 13:57:14 [alert] 26013#26013: *1013 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:57:15 [alert] 26013#26013: *2025 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:57:16 [alert] 26013#26013: *3037 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 13:57:31 [alert] 26013#26013: *4050 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 14:01:02 [alert] 26013#26013: *5064 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8000"
2020/12/20 14:01:04 [alert] 26013#26013: *6076 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "localhost:8000"
```

I Googled these errors, but came up with nothing. **Can someone tell me why is my nginx displaying `500 - Internal server error` and how can I get both Gunicorn and nginx to run on the same address and port (if that's even possible)?**

Comment: Two things cannot listen on same port that is networks 101, you are making nginx listen on 8000 but proxying to same port in config

Comment: @iklinac OK. Can you tell me how can I change my config files so I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @iklinac mentions, you cant have two ports config to the same id.  The port should be 80 like in [the tutorial you mentioned](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-10). Not 8000 as you have in the original post.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;
}
```